# Kafka Streams join - table too large

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I'd like to use the Kafka Streams API to perform a left join on a KStream with a KTable to add some fields of the table to the stream.

Everything works fine with a smaller version of the table (around 1,300 entries) containing all relevant entries.

Once I use the whole table (around 200,000 entries) I get a `NullPointerException` in the line where I get the relevant field of the Avro message (GenericRecord) of the KTable.

When I perform the same left join operation in KSQL, the added fields from the table are NULL. The relevant join keys exist in the table, but querying them in KSQL takes approx. 20 seconds until they show up.

**Is it possible that the table is too large to perform a left join? 
If that's the case, is there anything I can do to make the join work using the whole table?**

For development purposes I'm currently using Confluent Platform with a single Kafka broker and all topics have just a single partition.

Stack Trace:

> ```
> [myclass-68507371-7b8e-4bdc-8715-73d0307c9058-StreamThread-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks - stream-thread [myclass-68507371-7b8e-4bdc-8715-73d0307c9058-StreamThread-1] Failed to process stream task 3_0 due to the following error:
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at MyClass.lambda$main$6(MyClass.java:184)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamKTableJoinProcessor.process(KStreamKTableJoinProcessor.java:73)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:117)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:183)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:162)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:122)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:87)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:364)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedStreamsTasks.process(AssignedStreamsTasks.java:199)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:420)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:890)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:805)
>   at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:774)
> ```

The field is nullable in the Avro schema.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace? Because RocksDB is used to store the table state, and hence, data is spilled to disk, the size of the table should not be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the stack trace indicates (the error originate from `MyClass.lambda$main$6(MyClass.java:184)`), the exception from your own code, that must be your `ValueJoiner` implementation. As you do a `leftJoin()`, the passed in "KTable" value may be `null`. I assume your code does not handle `null` correctly. If you want to avoid getting `null` at all and drop a KStream records if there is no corresponding KTable record instead, you could use `join()` instead of `leftJoin()`.

Comment: Ok, I could surround the corresponding line with a `try catch` to ignore the `NullPointerException`.But this doesn't solve my problem that the field is `NULL` even though the values and corresponding keys definitely exist in the KTable and that it works with a smaller KTable. Is there any configuration that defines how long a `leftJoin()` searches for the key in the KTable until it stops and returns null?

Comment: Well, it depends on the order data is processed. When you start your application, both topics will be processed interleaved, based on the record timestamps. Hence, if for example your first KStream record has ts=10 and key=A, and your first KTable record hard ts=15 and key=A, the KStream record would be processed first, and the join would be executed against an empty table... Note that the join has temporal semantics.

Comment: I assume that your bigger dataset just does not have correct timestamps and KStream-side records for a certain key and processed before their corresponding KTable side records are inserted into the table. Hence, you should inspect the timestamps of your data. This slides may help to understand temporal semantics better: https://www.slideshare.net/ConfluentInc/streams-tables-and-time-in-ksql There is also a blog post about it: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I inspected the timestamps and noticed that it takes approx. 5 minutes until all data is written into the corresponding topic of the table. When I start sending data to the topic of the stream only afterwards, then the join works fine. However, when I use KSQL instead of Kafka Streams API, fields added from the table are still null even though all table entries have earlier timestamps than all stream entries. Any suggestions on why it now works with the Streams API but not with KSQL?